# Mobile Portrait: too much white space to the right of main elements

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, scale, viewport

I am trying to get the splashpage of my cargocollective site to scale to the mobile phone browser window. Everything is good apart from there is A LOT of white space to the right of the main elements which you can scroll along to. There is no need for all this extra space. I am wondering if the scaling is doubling the width somehow?

[MY SITE](http://www.danieltuffour.com)

If someone wouldn't mind opening up the site on their mobile device and telling me how to fix all thie extra width I'd really appreciate it.

Here is the code I am using to scale up:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
$(function(){
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
var ww = ( $(window).width() < window.screen.width ) ? $(window).width() : window.screen.width;       //get proper width
var mw = 320; // min width of site
var ratio =  ww / mw; //calculate ratio
if( ww < mw){ //smaller than minimum size
$('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ',   minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
}else{ //regular size
$('#Viewport').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
}
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you attach a screen capture with what you are seeing? At even possible mark it up with the desired changes.

Comment: Tested on Android 4.1; splash screen looks ok. Also tested it with Browserstack on Android 4.4 emulator, but it seems the user-agent query doesn't work on that (so the picture on your splashscreen remains at the original size). One question though; why are you using javascript instead of CSS media queries? Because if I resize my desktop browser I get scrollbars instead of scaling content...

Comment: The javascript doesn't actually work! I removed the code and no difference. I am going to start from scratch and use media queries only...best way to learn properly!